# HTTPS network link for Google Earth

Tags: ssl, https, kml, google-earth, pki

I'm currently using Google Earth Pro 7.3.0.3830.  I'm trying to access our KML feed behind an https link.  The web server is using a self-signed cert that has a self-signed user cert associated with it (same CA).  On Windows, I have the CA cert in the trusted windows store as well as the user certificate (both show up in chrome and IE).  If I use the Google Earth plugin within Chrome, I can create a network link with https and access the feed.  If I use the stand alone Google Earth app, I can't access it (red dot on the folder).

If I change the web server to allow http access and change the feed link, it displays fine on the standalone Google Earth app, (but using just http isn't desirable).

I can't figure out how to get Google Earth to use the client certificate to authenticate the https request to the web server.  This is an issue for running Google Earth Pro in both Windows 10 and Centos 7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Google Earth Pro 7.3.1.4507. It has the required ssl fix.

Please refer release notes
https://support.google.com/earth/answer/40901?hl=en

Comment: Can you accept my answer? (Mark it as Green tick) bcoz when other searching the same. They will find it as useful.

Comment: Sorry... New to actually asking questions instead of just looking them up!  Checked.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [release notes](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/maps/opv-ok9poRI) for 7.3, SSL client certificates aren't supported in Google Earth Pro 7.3. I'm not sure, but the older versions may have support for them which you can [download here](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/168344?vid=0-750173459475-1507733967202).

Comment: Thank you for the response.